# Is there a way to duplicate characters on a single line using regular expression?

Tags: notepad++, regex, textpad

I want to know if there's a way I can duplicate characters that's part of a single line without duplicating the whole line, using regular expression, and add them to the beginning of a line, that way I won't have to do it manually and risk causing error.

I want to be able to replace values like this

```
pl=100
pr=100
pj=100
bl=100
br=100
```

With this

```
pl=pl=100
pr=pr=100
pj=pj=100
bl=bl=100
br=br=100
```

Essentially copying the first three characters and adding them to the beginning of the line in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use this regexp:

```
^(...)(.*)$
```

this is to duplicate the first 3 characters, if you want to duplicate anything up to and including the first character "=", use:

```
^([^=]=)(.)$
```

with the replacement string for both cases:

```
\1\1\2
```

Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/pK7xN3/1